# Rail Can't find Railites - RBENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

RUBY 2.7.6
Bundler version 2.1.4

No matter what version of rails I use in the GEMFILE
I get the following error

```
undler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 6.0.0)
```

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '6.1.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe because you have an outdated version of `sass-rails`.

Try the followings steps:

1. Remove gem versions for `sass-rails` from Gemfile.lock and run `bundle update`
2. If above didnt work, delete the `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`, if you have no conflicting explicit gem version in your Gemfile to start with. So if this fails, remove version numbers from the Gemfile.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No Gemfile.lock already deleted that to get NEW gems brought in....will try the sass-rails update and see what happens... thanks